# Actionscript 3, constrain "character" within bounds

Tags: actionscript-3, bounds, box, bounding

So basically I have this point and clik game, the character moves where you click but I'd like to constrain its movements within a certain area, this could be easy if this area was a rectangle but to give a more tridimensional look to the backgroung i need this area to be more complex

see this image (blue= background, pink= bounding area (the floor)) :

[image]

any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you create the floor and walls?  Please show your relevant code.

Comment: well, The easiest solution would be create a button of irregular shape, and upon click on it you can move the character, unlike the movieclip, buttons define area from given shape not rectangular :)

Comment: Thank you Sameer, didn't know about this. I'll give it a try. Still, i forgot to mention that i want to, in case of click out of bounds, move the character to the given X and to the max Y of the floor for the given X...and this is the main issue